# Jquery - Loop through multiple lists

Tags: jquery

I am trying to loop through multiple lists on a page and depending on the number of items per list, I want to get the height of the each li and set the max height (for 5 items) and set a scrollbar.

I have the following script that goes through each list found and returns the length correctly but I cannot get the height of each li. Thanks for any help.

JQUERY::

```
        $(".list-item").each(function () {

            var sum = 0;

            var getLength = $(this).children().children().children('ol li').length;
            console.log(getLength);
            //Get length of list items and add scroll bar if more than 5
            if (getLength > 5) {
                $(this).addClass('maxLength');

                $('.maxLength ol li:lt(5)').each(function () {
                    sum += $(this).height();
                    console.log(sum);
                });

                $('.maxLength ol').css({ maxHeight: sum + 'px', overflow: 'auto' });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of counting children and set height, You can wrap your list in div and add the following css
*style:*

```
div{
 max-height:125px(your choice);//The height that 5 li elemtns occupies
 overflow:auto;
 display:inline-block;
}
div li{
 line-height:25px(your choice);
}
```

*Html:*

```
<div>
  <ul> 
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
<div>
```

I hope this would solve your problem...

Comment: Thanks Rama :) Sadly as there will be multiple lists on an individual page, with the chance of different line heights, I need to loop through and get the heights sadly.